# Python Celery group() - TypeError: [...] argument after ** must be a mapping, not long

Tags: django, celery

I'm trying to run a celery (3.1.17) task that executes further tasks in a group but I always run into errors. This is how I set up the code:

```
from celery import task, group

@task
def daily_emails():

    [...]

    all_tasks = []

    for chunk in range(0, users.count(), 1000):
        some_users = users[chunk:chunk+1000]
        all_tasks.append(write_email_bunch.subtask(some_users, execnum))

    job = group(all_tasks)
    # result = job.apply_async()
    # job.get()
    result = job.delay()
    print result
    results = result.join()
    print results

    print "done writing email tasks"
    count = sum(results)
    print count


@task
def write_email_bunch(some_users, execnum):

    [...]

    return len(some_users) - skipped_email_count
```

And this is the output:

```
<GroupResult: 3d766c85-21af-4ed0-90cb-a1ca2d281db1 [69527252-8468-4358-9328-144f727f372b, 6d03d86e-1b69-4f43-832e-bd27c4dfc092, 1d868d1b-b502-4672-9895-430089e9532e]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_daily_emails.py", line 8, in <module>
    daily_emails()
  File "/var/www/virtualenvs/nt_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 420, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/nt_dev/nt/apps/emails/tasks.py", line 124, in daily_emails
    results = result.join()
  File "/var/www/virtualenvs/nt_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 642, in join
    interval=interval, no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/var/www/virtualenvs/nt_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 870, in get
    raise self.result
TypeError: write_email_bunch() argument after ** must be a mapping, not long
```

So I get a GroupResult but somehow Im unable to join it or further process it.
And when I use *write_email_bunch.s(some_users, execnum)* I get this exception:

```
  File "/var/www/virtualenvs/nt_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 870, in get
    raise self.result
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

How would I wait for all the Group Tasks to be completed to continue afterwards? 
*job.get()* gives me this exception:

```
TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subtask` takes a tuple of args, a dict of kwargs and task options so it should be called like this:

```
    all_tasks.append(write_email_bunch.subtask((some_users, execnum)))
```

note that we are passing it a tuple containing the args

Also you shouldn't wait on a task inside a task - this can cause deadlocks. In this case I reckon `daily_emails` does not need to be a celery task - it can be a regular function that creates a canvas object and runs apply async.

```
def daily_emails():

    all_tasks = []

    for chunk in range(0, users.count(), 1000):
        some_users = users[chunk:chunk+1000]
        all_tasks.append(write_email_bunch.subtask(some_users, execnum))

    job = group(all_tasks)
    result = job.apply_async()
    return result.id
```

Comment: hi scytale, thanks for your answer! that was in fact the main problem. thanks so much for solving!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer you could be using `chunks` here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks

```
@app.task
def daily_emails():
    return write_email.chunks(users, 1000).delay()

@task
def write_email(user):
    [...]
```

It may be beneficial to do it manually if getting several objects at once
from the db is important.  You should also consider that the model objects will be serialized here, to avoid that you can send the pk only and refetch the model in the task, or send the fields that you care about (like email address or whatever is required to send that email to the user).

Comment: thats neat! thanks so much for the great work on celery!